# its an program involving methods

Tags: java, methods, overloading

write a program in java using a method `Discount()`, to calculate a single discount or a successive discount. Use overload methods `Discount (int)`, `Discount (int,int)` and `Discount (int,int,int)` to calculate single discount and successive discount respectively. Calculate and display the amount to be paid by the customer after getting discounts on printed price of an article.

this is the question and i understood that in the methods `Discount(int,int)` and `Discounts(int,int,int)` we have to take succesive disscounts and printed price but i am not getting what to do in the first method i.e `Discount(int)`

any help would be appreciated

Comment: *i am not getting what to do in the first method i.e `Discount(int)`* 
If you made the program and there are nobody else's specs, you must delete it, if not, please show us this specifications

Comment: And you should look out for a new teacher since yours obviusly doesn't even know Java naming conventions!

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is pretty straight forward.

For single discount, your code should look something like this

```
// The selling price is simply (item cost * 0.9)
price = item.discount(0.9);
```

Answer (score 0):

what i think is that you have to pass the percent value
e.g

//if the discount percent is 20%

int price=Market.Discount(20);//assuming the method will return int

........
.......
//method
public int Discount(int discpercnt)
{
int price=
}